# How to identify deleted sequence of the recurring event of Google Calendar?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have to synchronize My Calendar control with Gmail Events. I am getting issue in case of deleting an event of a recurring event.

Ex. There is 1 weekly RecurrenceEvent. Every Sunday, Monday.

If I delete any particular event of Sunday, I need RecurrenceIndex or Sequence number of that deleted sunday event to manage in my local calendar.

I just get RecurrenceEventId of that deleted event and Status "calncelled". But I don't get any number to identify number of the sequence/index.

I have following code to get events.

```
var x = CalendarListHelper.list(service, null);
foreach (var item in x.Items)
{
    if (!(item.AccessRole == "owner"))
    continue;
    var y = CalendarListHelper.get(service, item.Id);
    var events = service.Events.List(y.Id).Execute();
    foreach (var myEvent in events.Items)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(string.Format("Summary:{0} Status{1}", myEvent.Summary.ToString(), myEvent.Status.ToString));
    }
}
```

Can anybody please suggest me how to get deleted RecurrenceIndex?

Answer (score 0):

A recurring instance in Google Calendar can be identified by a combination of two fields - recurringEventId and originalStart. The original start is a pointer to the sequence of times generated by the recurring event so it also tells you where in the event that place is. There is no field called recurrenceIndex as far as I know.